# Tool to check for unused CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a tool to check for unused CSS tags in a CSS file?

The reason I am asking is that I have a lot of old/unused tags in my CSS file. I have a website I have been running for a while and have updated the pages many time, so old CSS tags remains there.

I would like a tool that check for all tags found ina  page and cross check with the one in CSS file, and let me know all tags that were unused so I could simply delete them from my CSS file to make it smaller.

Comment: You should probably read [what's on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I believe their is many tools out their, do a simple google search and many will come up, I'm unsure how genuine these tools are though, goodluck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chrome developer tools,refer following.

http://www.labnol.org/internet/remove-unused-css/28635/

Comment: Thanks Web World, looking like a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this node.js tool to find unused css: http://davidwalsh.name/uncss for tutorial or https://github.com/giakki/uncss for github